# adjacency matrix from transaction matrix in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, adjacency-matrix

I have a transaction dataframe as follow, which the indices are transactions and columns are products. A small subset of this data is as below:

```
d_frame
Out[213]: 
    P1  P2  P3  P4
T1   1   1   0   1
T2   1   0   1   1
T3   1   0   1   0
T4   1   1   0   1
```

It says that the products P1, P2 and P4 have all bought together in transaction T1 and so forth.
Now I want to create adjacency matrix from this dataframe which sums the number of each co-purchased products together. The adjacency matrix would be as follow:

```
d_adj
Out[214]: 
    P1  P2  P3  P4
P1   0   2   2   3
P2   2   0   0   2
P3   2   0   0   1
P4   3   2   1   0
```

The matrix shows that P1 and P2 have bought together in transactions T1 and T4, therefore P1P2 and P2P1 cell in adjacency matrix should be 2 and so on.

I thought I could create the adjacency from Networkx package and have tried the below code:

```
test = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(d_frame, create_using = nx.MultiGraph)
```

but the below error has raised:

> ('Columns must match Indices.', "['T3', 'T1', 'T2', 'T4'] not in columns")

I have also thought about creating edges list creating from permutations of products in each transaction, but since my dataframe is huge, that would not be an efficient way.

So any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby by each column, take the sum, and then concatenate them.

```
import pandas as pd

d_frame = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,1,0,1], [1,0,1,1] ,[1,0,1,0], [1,1,0,1]], index = ['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4'], columns=['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4'])

d_adj = pd.concat([d_frame.groupby(col).sum() for col in d_frame.columns]).loc[1] # loc[1] chooses the values where the column is 1

d_adj.fillna(0, inplace = True)

d_adj.index = d_adj.columns

Out[95]:
     P1   P2   P3   P4
P1  0.0  2.0  2.0  3.0
P2  2.0  0.0  0.0  2.0
P3  2.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
P4  3.0  2.0  1.0  0.0
```

When concatenating, don't pass `sort = False` otherwise the columns will be out of alignment.